# How to reuse subclasses on two parent classes?

Tags: java, oop

Imagine having class A as base class and classes B and C as subclasses that extend class A. After that you realise that you need class D that has different properties than class A, but you still want the same classes B and C without any changes. Is it possible to somehow reuse classes B and C so that they can extend class D?

Comment: What do classes B and C have to do with D? Why do they suddenly need to derive from a different class?

Comment: Well I have a set of data and the class A contains data that is used in both classes B and C. Now I want to return a different base set of data, but the B and C data stays the same.

Lets say you have an Request class and it contains person that requested the request and list of companies that need to recive this Request. User should be able to see the list of companies that he requested but to him is not important user property because it is him. On the other hand when company sees Request it should see User, but not other companies that recived this request.

Comment: From that description B and C shouldn't even be inheriting A in the first place, instead they should take it as a parameter (in the constructor or a method or ...)

Comment: Hmm it makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't totally understand what you are trying to do but in Java you can't extend two base classes and even if you could (like in C++) it is usually not a good idea. Did you consider composition instead of inheritance, it is usually the preferred design technique in these situations.